# WCF service and Biztalk service configuration error

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, biztalk, orchestration

I have a WCF web service which calls  a biztalk service( ie Orchestration). When i do the unit test i am getting following error:

Test method Goudse.BcVerzekering.Bts2006.InkCol.Business.UnitTests.UnitTest1.VerzekeringFacade_Goed threw exception:  System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration. (C:\Inetpub\DeGoudse.MKB\VerzekeringFacade\web.config line 50).

Its pointing to web.config, but  which is generated by the system itself...

Any insight will be  very helpful?

Comment: What do your .svc and your web.config files look like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=vs_TaDeScoIC&pg=PA534&lpg=PA534&dq=binding+named+%27WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync%27&source=bl&ots=6k17y-29mn&sig=Y4WEWgoQnpLXWf2QHmAYid8nB-8&hl=en&ei=9PZyTLnnHIO78gahmuyDDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=binding%20named%20%27WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync%27&f=false)?  It should be added to the app.config to work properly.